# How do I remove empty space using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have an object with a value that I save to a SQL database.  When I run a report on the SQL database, I occasionally display a `&#x20;` in the report.  I tried cleaning up the properties in my objects before saving them to SQL by using the following Regex:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 - , = % & ( )]");
myObject.Description = rgx.Replace(myObject.Description, "");
```

The Regular expression is doing a good job removing some unwanted text.  How do I use a Regular expression to remove `&#x20;` ?

Comment: Why not just `myObject.Description = myObject.Description.Replace("&#x20;", "");` ?

Comment: it is a white space so use \s

Comment: You don't need a regular expression to do it, do you? I assume that `myObject.Description` is a string so you can call Trim().

Comment: You probably want to pass your `string` through [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx). This will decode entities such as `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&#x20;` to the correct characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your string into the original regex delimited by `|`

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9-,=%&()#\s]|&#x20;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the space with nothing:

```
myObject.Description = myObject.Description.Replace(@"\s", @"");
```